# Solution of triangle

Tags: geometry

In triangle $ABC$, if angle $A=30$, area of $ABC=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}a^2$, then what is $\cos(B-C)$ equal to?

I tried to solve this question by using area formulae and got my final result as $\sin B\sin C=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$. Is it okay to directly say $B=120$ or $B=30$ from here, or are there more possible values?

Comment: It is not clear what you are after. The angles at $B$ and $C$ can be anything, so long as they add up to $150^{\circ}$.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't get (a2) was $a^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's okay, as long as you justify it.

Note that $\cos(B-C) = \cos(B)\cos(C) + \sin(B)\sin(C)$. By the sine-area formula,

$$\frac{1}{2} bc \sin(A) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} a^2 \implies bc = \sqrt{3}a^2.$$

Also, by the law of sines,

$$\frac{bc}{\sin(B)\sin(C)} = \frac{a^2}{\sin(A)^2} \implies \sin (B) \sin (C) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$$

Additionally, since we are dealing with a triangle,

$$B+C = 150^\circ \text{ and } B, C > 0$$

Now, let us solve for $B, C$. We have $\sin(B)\sin(150^\circ - B) = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$. Equivalently, this is by product-to-sum

$$\frac{15 \sin (2B - 60^\circ)+13}{30} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}.$$

Solving this is simple, and gives $B = 30^\circ, 120^\circ$, and thus $C = 120^\circ, 30^\circ$. Either pair should work just fine.

To finish, we get $\cos(90^\circ) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Given 
\begin{align} 
\angle A&=30^\circ
,\\
S&=\tfrac{\sqrt3}4\,a^2
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

By the sine rule, the radius of the circumscribed circle
of $\triangle ABC$ is

\begin{align}
R&=\frac{a}{2\sin A}=a
,
\end{align}

and the height $|AH|=h_a$ of $\triangle ABC$
\begin{align}
h_a&=\frac{2S}{a}
=
\tfrac{\sqrt3}2\,a
.
\end{align}

Since $\cos(B-C)=\cos(C-B)$, 
let's assign the label $B$ 
to the bigger angle of the two.

Then we can construct the circle of arbitrary radius $R=a$,
in which $\angle COB=2\angle CAB=60^\circ$
and equilateral $\triangle COB$ shares 
the side $|BC|=a$ with the $\triangle ABC$.

[image]

Since the height $|AH|$ of $\triangle ABC$
equals to the height $|OD|$ of $\triangle COB$,
\begin{align}
|AH|=h_a&=\tfrac{\sqrt3}2\,a=|OD|
,
\end{align}
$OABC$ is a rectangle and

\begin{align}
|OA|=a&=|DH|
,\\
|BH|&=|BD|=\tfrac12\,a
,\\
|AB|&=a
.
\end{align}

Hence $\triangle OAB$ is also equilateral,
$\triangle ABC$ is isosceles, $\angle C=\angle  A=30^\circ$
$\angle B=120^\circ$, 
$\cos(B-C)=\cos90^\circ=0$.